# Eval Error in Shell

Tags: bash

I am creating and setting a variable in my shell script using following expression.

```
eval "test2"="'Test Name's Test'"
```

But it results in following error

```
-sh: eval: line 1: syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an idea of what will actually be run when `eval`-ing some string, try to **`echo` it first**. `eval`-ing it is like *copying the output of `echo` into the shell and running that*:

```
echo "test2"="'Test Name's Test'"
test2='Test Name's Test'
```

There are three single quotes there, which will never run. And since you can't include single quotes in Bash single-quoted strings (it doesn't even support backslash escaping, unlike many other languages), you'll have to use double quotes if you want to `eval` something like that:

```
echo "test2"="\"Test Name's Test\""
test2="Test Name's Test"
```

But as @daniel pointed out, the `eval` is unnecessary. And [you shouldn't be using `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) in any case - The only case I have ever seen of useful `eval` is with [`getopt` output](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/scripts/make-links.sh#L68).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear here. **Unterminated quote** is probably referring to the three single quotes on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

First: why the `eval`? You could just say `test="..."`.

Second: You can't put a single quote `'` into a string delimited by single quotes. You can't even escape it with a backslash. So to put a single quote into such a string, you have to end the single-quoted string and insert the single quote (which has to be escaped):

```
test2='Test Name'"'"'s Test'; echo $test2
test3='Test Name'\''s Test'; echo $test3
```

The problem with `eval` is that it adds another expansion round, so you have to escape the internal `"`'s

```
eval test2="'Test Name'\"'\"'s Test'"; echo $test2
eval test3="'Test Name'\''s Test'"; echo $test3
```

Comment: I am using eval to create a variable assign with a value when someone wants calls my function with a string representing the name of new variable created